# Android horizontal layout with dynamically expanding TextView on the right

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create an Android horizontal layout design with a vertical `LinearLayout` on the left and a `TextView` on the right, as shown below:

```
¦==========================¦
¦      A1     ¦            ¦
¦             ¦     BB     ¦
¦      A2     ¦            ¦
¦==========================¦
```

The vertical `LinearLayout` on the left contains two `TextView` elements and sections A and B take the entire screen width. All `TextView` elements contain dynamically assigned text content.

I want the width of the `TextView` B to be determined by its content so that it expands or shrinks to show its entire content (which can't wrap and must be shown in a single line), while the width of the `LinearLayout` A on the left is to be determined by the width of `TextView` B, as shown below:

`TextView` B expands:

```
¦==========================¦
¦     A1    ¦              ¦
¦           ¦     BBB      ¦
¦     A2    ¦              ¦
¦==========================¦
```

`TextView` B shrinks:

```
¦==========================¦
¦      A1       ¦          ¦
¦               ¦    B     ¦
¦      A2       ¦          ¦
¦==========================¦
```

My idea was to use a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/A1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/A2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but with the above layout, if the content of `TextView` A1 is long enough, it takes the whole screen width and `TextView` B disappears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the right textview to wrap content and make the left linearlayout use the weight attribute as

```
android:layout_weight="1.0"
```

This will tell the linearlayout to take the remaining space. But if the text is too long, either reduce the size of the text or elipsize.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I suggest to use RelativeLayout

I posted a code in pastebin that shows an example 
http://pastebin.com/Ttc42C69

You can improve this by using layout_margin.

A benfit of using ...

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/aonetext"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/aonetext"
```

... in atwotext is, that if you want to adjust the margin of a1 and a2 you just have to do this in a1 and it will affect both

//Edit

Another positive effect: You save on level of xml hierachy.

Comment: +1 for the good alternative solution. However, I prefer to stick to my original `LinearLayout` solution, which I find easier to manage.

Comment: According to romain guy should be aware of that weight parameter can cause a slow down experience of your ui because its measured twice http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/

Comment: Good point, I may think of changing my layout. I made a little change to your code though: [http://pastebin.com/riYtm1xf](http://pastebin.com/riYtm1xf). The change is in the layout of the `TextView` with id `@+id/atwotext`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to set the width of the `TextView` A using getSuggestedMinimumWidth()?

I want to say:

```
a.setWidth(a.getSuggestedMinimumWidth());
```